# Couldn't open any java .jar application file after installing OS X Capitan

Tags: mac, macos, java

I couldn't open any java .jar application file after installing OS X El Capitan. The only message after opening always is:
Java-Jar-File "ABC.jar" couldn't be opened.

I installed both jdk1.8.0_65.jdk and jdk1.8.0_66.jdk but doesn't work at all. Also has installed the legacy JDK 1.6 for OS X.

Comment: From which exact place did you install Java - and what was the exact command line you called and the exact error

Comment: From which exact place did you install Java: from oracle website: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html
what was the exact command line you called and the exact error: I didn't use command line, just double-clicking in a .jar file to execute it. Then it showed the error above.

Comment: What does java -version show on the command line?